# Pygame: how to do a collision area of sprites lesser than its rect?

Tags: pygame

I would like that my sprites had a collision area lesser than its rect.
for example:

```
sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
image = pygame.surface.Surface((100, 100))
image.fill((0,0,0))
sprite.image = image
sprite.rect = image.get_rect()
# I would like that collision methods use this rect
sprite.collision_rect = image.get_rect()
sprite.collision_rect.width = 10
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can simply use:

```
sprite.collision_rect.colliderect(other.collision_rect)    # returns True if they collide
```

Comment: Thanks for the Unmei answer!
It works, but i would like to use this 'collision_rect' in methods like  pygame.sprite.groupcollide and pygame.sprite.spritecollideany

Comment: I see. In that case I think the easiest thing might be to just re-check the sprite dictionary that returns from those methods using the collision_rect.colliderect method. The longer solution might be to override whichever group method you want to use to check on sprite.collide_rect if it exists and sprite.rect otherwise.